# Cannot get Clickatell-provided HTTP API to send MMS messages

Tags: mms, clickatell

According to my Clickatell Americas 2-Way SMS/MMS service at:
https://www.clickatell.com/downloads/http/Clickatell_HTTP.pdf
Page: 21 Section: "5.4 MMS Push"

One should be able to send a Multimedia Messaging Service message by pasting this URL into a browser:

http://api.clickatell.com/mms/ind_push?user=[username]&api_id=[APINumber]&password=[password]&to=[ToNumber]&from=[FromNumber]&mo=1&mms_subject=My+message&mms_class=80&mms_expire=1000&mms_from=[My+Name]&mms_url=https%3A%2F%2F[myURL]%2F[Filename.mms]

Note the URL part is encoded, in compliance with the specification in the clickatell .pdf.

Also: The I have verified my .mms file '[Filename.mms]' is publically-readable and downloadable at [myURL]

However, when I paste the URL in a browser, I get a 'Routing error (status 9)' message in the Sent Messages Report in my Clickatell account. There is no other debug info available in my Clickatell account.

And Clickatell support - after much effort on my part - finally replied,

"I have escalated this and the feedback is that currently we do not assist with any integration or setups with regards to integration.

The http/s API reference guide which i believe you already have is the only guide we have on integration.

clickatell.com/downloads/http/Clickatell_HTTP.pdf"

IMO this is a could be a very relevant and useful tool for anybody who sends SMS messages through the Clickatell Gateway...as PICTURE messages. MMS through the Clickatell Gateway is going to be a really big and popular thing once we work the kinks out of it!

Not only does it allow the inclusion of pictures, it also allows individual messages to be up to 1600 characters in length as well. Pretty cool.

Can we put our heads together and figure out how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaron

A routing error would indicate something wrong with your account setup (e.g. account type or something like that)

I've pinged our support manager to get in contact with you and get you an answer for this.

Cheers, Arno (disclaimer, I work for Clickatell)

Comment: Thanks Arno, I haven't heard from Clickatell about this.  (:

Comment: I had one of the Service Centre managers send you a message, but I can't see his response. I'll send you a direct message with the details.

Comment: Your profile doesn't have a way for me to contact you. How can I make contact?

Comment: Thanks Arno. Email me at aaron.thain@yau.us

Comment: I DID get this response form the Service Centre Manager: "The routing errors are caused by the omission of the two-way parameters. “from”” with the value set to your us long number and “mo” with the value set to 1 as per the example below"" "Please note however that this feature is not supported within the USA as only plain text messaging is supported within the US." 

I responded, "Can I send an MMS Message FROM an IP Address in the US to a mobile phone OUTSIDE the US?

Can you tell me where I can find a list of countries to which I CAN send a MMS message?"

Comment: I did make the corrections, adding the &mo=1 and the &from=xxxxxxxxxx
...but I STILL get a routing error.

Comment: Conclusion: Clickatell does NOT support MMS messaging in the United States. Bummer.